# Find the indefinite integral of $\int\frac{1}{(\frac{\cos^2x}{4}+\sin^2x)^2} \, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{1}{(\frac{\cos^2x}{4}+\sin^2x)^2}\,dx$$
I do not know how to proceed, maybe is there any identity to make it easier to integrate?

Comment: this is called elliptic integral and it can be looked up in Neil Sloane's table of integral. Its been there for a while ...

Comment: Substitute $u=\cot(x)$:
$$\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\cos^2(x)}{4}+\sin^2(x)\right)^2}~dx=\int \frac{16(1+\cot^2(x))\csc^2(x)}{(4+\cot^2(x))^2}~dx=-16\int \frac{u^2+1}{(u^2+4)^2}~du$$
Your integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @DeepSea where can I find that table of integrals?

Comment: @G.nino No elliptic Integrals.  I got this identity 
$$\frac{1}{\left(\sin ^2(x)+\frac{\cos ^2(x)}{4}\right)^2}=\frac{64}{(5-3 \cos (2 x))^2}$$

Comment: @DeepSea: this is not an elliptic integral.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. Good to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution $x\mapsto\arctan t$ leads to

$$ \mathfrak{I}=\int\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)\left(\frac{1}{4(1+t^2)}+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2}\,dt=\int\frac{(1+t^2)}{\left(\tfrac{1}{4}+t^2\right)^2}\,dt $$
which is an elementary integral. For any $a>0$ we have
$$ \int\frac{dt}{a+t^2}=K_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\,\arctan\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}} $$
and by applying $\frac{d}{da}$ to both sides we get:
$$ \int\frac{dt}{\left(a+t^2\right)^2} = K_2+\frac{t}{2a(a+t^2)}+\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{a}}\,\arctan\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}} $$
from which:
$$ \int\frac{1+t^2}{\left(\tfrac{1}{4}+t^2\right)^2}\,dt = \color{blue}{K_3+\frac{6t}{1+4t^2}+5\arctan(2t)}.$$